# Decode of json uint8 array

Tags: json, decode

I received the uint8 array json style data and print it as strings, it shown like: AADAfwAAwH8AAMB/AAAAAAAAwH8AAMB/AADAfwAAAAAAAMB/AADAfwAAwH8AAAAAAADAfwAAwH8AAMB/AAAA

It should be some numbers, so I don't know how to decode it, it looks like Base64 but actually I cannot decode like that.

Answer (score 0):

What language?

`C#` to decode from JSON to bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);
```

`C++` to decode from JSON to bytes:

```
(uint8*)TCHAR_TO_UTF8(json)
```

Comment: MATLAB. I get these data as "string" in matlab, and don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: And did you try `bytes = unicode2native(unicodestr)` and `  bytes = unicode2native(unicodestr,encoding)` ?

Comment: I try it, it just change the char to ascii number not the real data